# How can I configure a Flask API to allow for token-protected user-specific responses?

Tags: python, python-2.7, flask

If I have a server end point that say does a simple task like initializes an API with a token that I generate client side, and then print the users account info.

1. Can I `initialize()` the API globally so the user can do other tasks after printing account info?

and

2. How does that affect other users `initializing()` and printing info if they do it at the same time?

I don't understand how this server works and any help would be great. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding you correctly, it sounds like the easiest way to accomplish what you're trying to do is to use the [flask-login](https://flask-login.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) module.

You will want to create an endpoint / Flask route (for example, '/login') that the user will send a POST request to with a username (and usually also a password). When the login is successful, the user's browser will have a cookie set with a token that will allow them to access Flask routes that have a @login_required decorator attached.

In your Python code for those routes, you will be able to access the "current_user", which will allow you to tailor your response to the particular user sending the request.

This way of doing things will allow you to deal with your first question, which seems to be about saving a user's identity across requests, and it will also allow you to deal with your second question, which seems to be about the problem of having different users accessing the same endpoint while expecting different responses.

Answer (score 0):

Nathan's answer points you in the right direction, but I'll make a comment about state and scope because you asked about multiple users.

Firstly, the normal way to do this would be for the `server` to generate the random token and send it back to the user.

```
client request 1 > init > create token > store along with init data > return token to user
client request 2 > something(token) > find data related to token > return data to user
```

When you run Flask (and most webapps) you try to make it so that each request is independent. In your case, the user calls an endpoint and identifies themselves by passing a token. If you make a record of that token somewhere (normally in a database) then you can identify that user's data by looking up the same token they pass on subsequent requests.

Where you choose to store that information is important. As I say a database is the normal recommended approach as it's built to be accessed safely by multiple people at the same time.

You might be tempted to not do the database thing and actually store the token / data information in a global variable inside python. Here's the reason why that's (probably) not going to work:

Flask is a wsgi server, and how it behaves when up and running depends on how it's configured. I generally use uwsgi with several different `processes`. Each process will have its own state that can't see one another. In this (standard / common) configuration, you don't know which process is going to receive any given request.

```
request 1 > init(token) > process 1 > store token in global vars
request 2 > other(token) >  process 2 > can't find token in global vars
```

That's why we use a database to store all shared information:

```
request 1 > init(token) > process 1 > store token in db
request 2 > other(token) >  process 2 > can find token db
```